# How to copy directory structure from one server to another without root user?

Tags: permissions, directory, file-copy, archive

I would like to know best way to copy directory structure from one server(Unix) to another (Linux):

- without root user
- servers are not connected (e.g. can't use SSH directly between them)
- I need to copy only folders and subfolders, without files
- permissions on folders must also bi transferred

So i have user@server1 with some directory structure. I need to copy this structure to user@server2 without files, with same permissions. Users on both servers have same permissions and are in the same group, servers are not connected.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that server1 is Unix, and server 2 is Linux. So when I try to execute proycon's code on Unix server I got message: tar: Not a recognized flag: z When I try Tom Hunt's option I got message: -printf is not a valid option. Also, worth to mention, user have different names, although they have same rights and are in same group. So I have user_xy@server1 and user_zx@server2

Comment: Not connected so you're looking for some offline approach (e.g. create `tar` file) ?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you'd do something like `rsync` or `scp`, but then the machines would indeed have to be connected. I'd go for using `tar` with `find` instead if you have no means of direct transfer, it can preserve users, permissions, and symlinks.

On one host:

```
$ find yourdirectory/ -type d | tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz --no-recursion --files-from -
```

Transfer the archive by any means (ftp? USB stick? smoke signals?)

On target host:

```
$ tar -xvzf archive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

On `server1`:

```
find . -type d -printf '%p\n%m\n' >dir_list
```

Transfer the file `dir_list` from server1 to server2 however you see fit.

On `server2`:

```
while read -r filename; do
    read -r perms
    mkdir -p "$filename"
    chmod "$perms" "$filename"
done <dir_list
```

This will create all the directories owned by the user you run as on `server2`. Changing the ownership cannot be done without superuser.

Comment: True. If handling this is necessary, you can use `-printf '%p\0%m\0'` and `read -d ''`.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for answers. Yes, both answers would be what I need. I forgot to mention that server1 is Unix, and server 2 is Linux. So when I try to execute proycon's code on Unix server I got message:

    tar: Not a recognized flag: z

When I try Tom Hunt's option I got message:

    -printf is not a valid option.

Also, worth to mention, user have different names, although they have same rights and are in same group. So I have user_xy@server1 and user_zx@server2